# Given a printf statement in C, how do I construct a char * buffer, and know its length?

Tags: c, printf, mpi, output-formatting

I have an MPI process that I need to print to a file.  The MPI system uses functional commands like MPI_File_iwrite, which accept a buffer (a char pointer, for instance)  and an integer length.  Then, the buffer is printed to the file.

So, in order to print what I need to print to the file, I need to somehow replace the printf function with a function that maps the formatting conversion to a char * buffer.  This is problematic, since the strings can vary in length...for instance:

```
printf("something %d, %d, %d, %f, etc.",x,y,z,p,d,...);
```

How do I recover the string that printf formatting produces, figure out what the length is, and pass it as a char * to the mpi function?

Comment: 1) `printf` is a function, not a statement. 2) `printf` does not generate a string (resp. a `char []`. 3) `char *` is a pointer to `char`, not an array.

Comment: If the `printf()` does something like `printf("%c", 0);`, then attempting to use `s(n)printf(some_buffer, ...); len = strlen(some_buffer);` will not determine the correct number of characters printed.  Best to use the return value of `snprintf()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want to use [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) to a sufficiently-large buffer.

If the buffer was sufficiently large, the return value of `snprintf` is equal to the number of characters printed. You can compute the length of the output string as the minimum of the size of the buffer and the return value of `snprintf`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `strlen()`; `snprintf()` tells you how many characters should have been supplied.  If the number of characters you supplied was too small, the output will have been truncated.

Comment: The whole idea of `snprintf` is that it can do a "dry run" with null buffer, to pre-calculate the required buffer length. So if you have `snprintf` at your disposal, use its power: do it in two-pass fashion. Of course, if the max buffer length is easily predictable, then it can be done in one shot. No need for `strlen` though, since all `...printf` functions return the length of the sequence they outputted.

Comment: @AnT If you have the stack space, in my experience it's more efficient to do the first `snprintf()` call with a fixed-sized local `char` array that's big enough to likely to work most of the time, and only if that fixed buffer is too small *then* dynamically allocate a large-enough buffer and make a second call to `snprintf()`.  `snprintf()` can be somewhat expensive, and `malloc()` may require locking that can impact performance, especially for multithreaded processes.

Comment: @AndreiTumbar accepted; had stepped away for the night.

Comment: You must add 1 to the return value of snprintf to get the minimum buffer size because of the null terminator.

Answer (score 5):

You can "print" 0 bytes to a `NULL` pointer with [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf). In that case, no string will be written, but `snprintf()` will still behave normally with respect to its return value. Then you can allocate a large enough buffer.

For instance:

```
size_t len;
len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "something %d, %d, %d, %f, etc.",x,y,z,p,d,...);
if (len > 0) {
    char *buf = malloc(len + 1);
    snprintf(buf, len + 1, "something %d, %d, %d, %f, etc.",x,y,z,p,d,...);
}
```

This is only valid in C99 and further.

Notice that `snprintf()` can return a negative value if there is a conversion error. The are only a few instances where this could happen, but they exist nonetheless. Depending on the specifier, its output could also be zero.

Comment: A user of this code will need to remember to call `free()` on `buf` after `buf` is no longer needed to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Note: `snprintf()` returns an `int`.  A negative return value indicates an error.

Comment: An *output* error. Is there any detectable output error that `snprintf()` could deal with?

Comment: @giusti: yes there is: an encoding error in a multibyte sequence in the format string or in a string argument for the current locale

Answer (score 3):

Based on your question, I think the answer is to use `sprintf()` or `snprintf()` rather than `printf()` - `sprintf()` outputs to a buffer and returns the number of characters written without any check that the passed buffer is large enough. `snprintf()` takes an additional argument specifying the maximum number of bytes to write (which is the safer approach).

```
char my_buf[MAX_LENGTH];
int bytes_written;

// using snprintf
bytes_written = snprintf(my_buf, MAX_LENGTH, "%d %d ...", arg0, arg1 ...);
```

Note that `sprintf()` and variants also require an additional byte for the terminator character `\0` so this should be reflected in your defined buffer size. The return value (number of bytes written) does not include the terminator character.

Comment: On the whole, it is best to forget about the existence of `sprintf()` and its relatives; you should really only use `snprintf()` because they protect you against buffer overflows.  That said, if you have confidence that your buffer is big enough and the output data small enough, `sprintf()` can still be used, but it would be preferable to emphasize `snprintf()` first and mention `sprintf()` in a throwaway comment.